# how to fix the probleme of importing keys from selenium

Tags: python, selenium

When I type the following code:

`from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import keys`

I got an error:

`ImportError: cannot import name 'keys' from 'selenium.webdriver.common.keys' (c:\users\*****\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\keys.py)`

How to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

You need to capitalize Keys

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

Comment: This should nail the OP